# Starting values for an nls model in R

Tags: r, parameterization, nls

I'm trying to fit an exponential model using nls, but I don't know how to select the starting values for the parameters. I know this question has been answered multiple times, but I spent some days surfing on forums and I couldn't find the solution for my particular case. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183653/getting-the-right-starting-values-for-an-nls-model-in-r) they showed the very same problem, but the solution of liniarizing the data taking logs doesn't work wor me, because the fit of the transformed data is not linear.
I would really appreciate a piece of advice here.

Here an example of my kind of data:

```
mes1 <- data.frame(CO2=c(354.68, 362.43, 374.12, 380.45, 385.92, 394.19, 400.2, 405.85, 407.81, 410.71, 414.77), time=c(1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101))

CO2i <- mes1$CO2[1]
Timei <- mes1$time[1]
exp_eq <- function(time,B,CO2i,a,Timei){B + (CO2i- B)^(-a*(Timei-time))}
```

I know other kind of equations might work better, but I must use this one since is the reference in the field.
The only thing I need is estimate the initial values for **a** and **B**

```
m <- nls(CO2 ~ exp_eq(time,B,CO2i,a,Timei)), data = mes1, start = list(B = 1, a = 1))
```

Many thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: I found many directly relevant answers by [searching](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=nls%20start*%20-self%20%20exp%20is%3aanswer) and going through the top few hits.

Comment: Many thanks @whuber I've readed carefully the different posts on this topic, but probably because I'm not profficient in R (and probably in statistics) I couldn't find a solution for my data. From this post [link] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160552/why-is-nls-giving-me-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter-estimates) I cannot estimate the initial parameters because one of them appears in two different parts of the model (and also data trend to an assymptot); I found multiple suggestions, but I couldn't make them work in my case. Many thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Additionally, my data tends to a limit, so I cannot estimate C.o as min("input")*0.5, as in the example

Comment: Sure you can--it is, after all, just an *estimate* to get things started. But you need to assign the estimate to the correct variable: as time increases, the function approaches $B,$ not $C_0,$ in the limit.  At the initial time, the function's value is$C_0.$ It's usually a good idea to graph your data and graph the function associated with your initial estimate to make sure they are reasonably close.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I see that when time increases, the function approaches B, and at initial time, the function is CO2i (constant), but I still don't know how to linearize the data for estimating initial values for B and a. Sorry, I feel so dumb. I applied logs at both sides, but I guess B hinders the proper liniarization of the data

Comment: Well, $a$ is the rate constant. Various ways to estimate it have been developed in different disciplines. A common one is to estimate the time the curve reaches 95% of its ultimate range and divide that by 3: this estimates $1/a.$  Another common one is to estimate the time the curve reaches 50% of its range (the "half life") and divide that by $\log(1/2)\approx 0.7:$ again this estimates $1/a.$ The main point, though, is by a little bit of trial and error in graphing your guesses you will quickly find some that already fit the data decently; the computer merely "polishes" that eyeball guess.

Comment: The range of your data is $60.$ Although that's likely not the full range, it's getting there, so divide it by two. The data have reached the midpoint of their range around time $40$ or so, so estimate $a \approx 1/40.$ Using the smallest $y$ value of $355$ to estimate $C_0$ and the largest $y$ value of $415$ to estimate $B,$ you will get a serviceable initial fit.

Comment: Again, many, many thanks. Even if I tried to put your initial values, I still get "Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model".   m.0 <- nls(CO2 ~ B + (mes1$CO2[1]- B)^(-a*(Time-(mes1$Time[1]))), data = mes1, start = list(B = 415, a = (1/40)))   Additionally, this is just one case, but I have hundreds of cases with different Bs and different ranges for ymin and ymax, so I will need to explore automated "eyeball guesses". Sometimes I only have data for the "linear part" of the exponential curve, and sometimes I have the whole assymptote. Again, many thanks for your support

Comment: Hi @whuber. Please, don't waist an extra second on that. I found a mistake in my equation, and now, it works! There is a section I wrote (CO2i- B)^(-a*(Timei-time)) but it should be (CO2i- B)*exp(-a*(Timei-time)) Many tnaks for your time!